# windows phone 8 disable map auto zoom on double tap

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps, here-api

How can I disable auto zoom on double tap for the maps:Map control?
I've tried "e.handled = true" inside the DoubleTap event handler, but that doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try the below link once,you can control the event handler.

http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/11/17/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control.html

Comment: That didn't seem to do it ie. setting e.handled = true in the manipulation completed event for the map control.